# Why are functions not available in global object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This script has different behavior based on whether it's run from the node js shell or stored in a script file passed to node.

Script:

```
var a = 1;
function b(){return 1;}
for(var k in global) console.log(k);
```

Output in shell (only last 4 lines are relevant IMO. Each of the 3 lines were copy/pasted sequentially into a node REPL instance running in Terminal on Mac OS X):

```
ArrayBuffer
Int8Array
Uint8Array
Int16Array
Uint16Array
Int32Array
Uint32Array
Float32Array
Float64Array
DataView
global
process
GLOBAL
root
Buffer
setTimeout
setInterval
clearTimeout
clearInterval
console
module
require
a
_
b
k
```

Output when run as a saved script (called `node myscript.js` from bash on Mac OS X):

```
ArrayBuffer
Int8Array
Uint8Array
Int16Array
Uint16Array
Int32Array
Uint32Array
Float32Array
Float64Array
DataView
global
process
GLOBAL
root
Buffer
setTimeout
setInterval
clearTimeout
clearInterval
console
```

Why are they different, and why can't my script see `a` and `b` in `global`?

EDIT: Adding an additional statement c = 2 changed the output. c was visible in both methods of running the script. This still doesn't explain a and b's presence when running the script from the shell though.

Comment: Can you add to your experiment: 1) A variable assignment without `var`: So just do a `c = 3`; 2) `console.log(this === global)`

Comment: Can you also detail how you pass these files to Node? (The exact command lines)

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this === global)`? Also, what happens when you iterate through the properties of `this` instead of `global`?

Comment: Using `this` doesn't help - it prints no keys when run as script file, and works the same as global when in REPL.

Comment: If only you would also test `console.log(this === global)` :/ (Maybe third time's the charm)

Comment: Ates I salute your persistence. `console.log(this===global) == false` in script, `== true` in REPL.

Comment: I think you've already got yourself and answer by TooTallNate below, but thanks anyway:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11030/discussion-between-trindaz-and-ates-goral)

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's because Node's REPL uses the "global" context as it's "this" (you can test that with `global === this`).

However, regular modules run in their own separate closure. So you can imagine it being *something* like this:

```
function (module, exports, global) {
  // your module code
}
```

So when you define a `var` in your and execute it as a script, you're really just defining it inside of a function closure. But in the REPL, you're defining the var at the global level.

Comment: Thanks @TooTallNate. When replacing `(for var k in global)` with `(for var k in this)` it prints nothing. Any hints on how I can iterate through symbols created by my script?

Comment: Inside a module, `this` points to the module's `exports`, not the global context. However, I believe that there is simply no way to iterate on closure variables. It's just a limitation of JavaScript.

Comment: @TooTallNate You can use brute force to iterate over all variable name combinations :P